# Pandas: split dataframe on signal threshold

Tags: python, pandas, signal-processing

I have a pandas dataframe where I've identified some regions that I'd like to split and analyze independently. For example here are five distinct regions:

[image]

generated from

```
df["signal"] = df["average"] > 0.70
df["blocked_signal"] = convolve1d(df.signal, [1,1,0,1,1])
```

How do I create five separate regions from the `blocked_signal` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups with

```
mask = df["average"].gt(.7)
rgns = mask.diff().iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
gb = df.assign(Region=rgns)[mask].groupby('Region')
```

I could show you more, but you didn't provide data to play with.

Comment: Why invert the sequence before and after applying `cumsum`? The impact on `cumsum` of the NaN value at the start of the result of `diff` can be mitigated by `mask.diff().fillna(True).cumsum()`, not?

Comment: Also, why use `assign`? Why not use `gb = df[mask].groupby(rgns)` instead?